# Does Lean 4 have syntax to refer to the current thing being defined?

Tags: lean, lean4, syntax

If I am defining a function (using `def` for example) then is there some way to refer to the function being defined inside its definition without using the name of the function, like how `this` is used in this invalid code:

```
def len : List a → Nat
  | [] => 0
  | _ :: list => 1 + this list
```

Comment: You can just use `len`. See [induction & recursion](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/induction_and_recursion.html)

Comment: @Couchy I know, I am asking if there exists a different way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want such a thing? It sounds like you're trying to solve a problem which is better solved in a different way. If that is so, please describe the wider original problem.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sometimes I want to prove theorems but not give them any name because it is hard to come up with a name for them. So I want some way to refer to the theorem within itself without giving it a name.

Comment: @adrian Theorems are usually proved by tactic induction, not syntactic recursion in Lean, so your original use case doesn't usually come up for them. And of course you still have to name a theorem in the end if you want to reference them in other theorems. The only exception is nested anonymous `have : ...` proofs, which are implicitly bound to `this`.

Comment: OK I suppose I will have to learn about tactics.